# Was the Reish Galuta considered the presumptive candidate for the Melech haMoshiach?

Tags: history, chutz-laaretz, messiah, malchut-royalty

The *Reish Galuta*, or [Exilarch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exilarch), was, from the time of Zerubavel until the abolition of the office *ca.* 1000 C.E. (with interregna), a Jewish political leader descended from *malchut beit David*. In some ways (see the Wikipedia article) he was treated as a legitimate king and heir to the Davidic line.

Was it assumed that the then-current *Reish Galuta* would reign as *Melech haMoshiach* if we were to have merited *Melech haMoshiach*'s reign?

Answer (score 4):

[Seder Olam Zutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seder_Olam_Zutta) seems to imply that the Reish Galuta was from the line of Yehoaichin, who was [cursed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeconiah#Curse) by Yirmiyahu that none of his descendants should ever be king.

Comment: I thought all descendents of Dovid Hamelech (except Bustenai) were killed in Bustenai's time?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin interesting, I'm not familiar with this tradition. David and Shlomo had many sons, though --- it seems plausible that male-line descendants who were not part of the reigning dynasty of Judah would have survived.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin One of the Geonim (I forget which) is quoted as claiming descent from _beit david_, but _not_ through Bustenai: neither his Jewish nor his (born) Persian wife.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin … R' Sherira Gaon; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bostanai

Comment: I’m not sure @sabbahillel’s edit is appropriate. The original answer was a negative, backed by Seder Olam Zutta. Bringing in Vayikra Rabba opens the question back up.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon OK I will make it a separate answer pointing out the Vayikra Rabba.

Answer (score 3):

However [Vayikra Rabba 19:6](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/midrash69/30midrash.htm) states that the curse was revoked and Zerubavel was part of the line of King David. I go into detail on this answer at [which kings must Moshiach descend from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/which-kings-must-moshiach-descend-from/37097#37097). Among other sources (besides Vayikra Raba) I point to the Abarbanel and Metzudas Dovid in Chagai and Zecharya as well as several possible lists of descendants into relatively modern times.