# What powers and responsibilities do wives of Jewish kings have in relation to the public?

Tags: halacha, history, women, malchut-royalty

It is known that a Jewish king has to be male, as quoted by an answer to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40324/could-mashiach-be-a-woman/) question.

What halachik powers did the queen (i.e. wife of the king) have within the kingdom?

Also, what historical documentation is there on this topic?

Comment: Correction, an APPOINTED King has to be male. Technically, there could be  a single female heir to the throne who would therefore become a female king. This came up in a shiur recently, so I can't quite recall what the source for this was...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky So Mashiach can be a women? Moshiach isn't appointed. S/he inherits the position from their great-great....grandfather Zerubavel.

Comment: @DoubleAA I have no idea. I just know that technically a female king could occur according to the laws of kingship and inheritance as they are currently understood by Chazal.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Possible, but not necessarily so. Minchas Chinuch 497:1 discusses this, but leaves it with וצ"ע.

Answer (score 1):

The queen had no official power, but they could influence the king. Often the mother of the king was a position of influence, [for example](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_I_Kings.6.6.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en):

> וַתָּבֹא בַת־שֶׁבַע אֶל־הַמֶּלֶךְ שְׁלֹמֹה לְדַבֶּר־לוֹ עַל־אֲדֹנִיָּהוּ וַיָּקָם הַמֶּלֶךְ לִקְרָאתָהּ וַיִּשְׁתַּחוּ לָהּ וַיֵּשֶׁב עַל־כִּסְאוֹ וַיָּשֶׂם כִּסֵּא לְאֵם הַמֶּלֶךְ וַתֵּשֶׁב לִימִינוֹ׃
> So Bathsheba went to King Solomon to speak to him about Adonijah. The king rose to greet her and bowed down to her. He sat on his throne; and he had a throne placed for the queen mother, and she sat on his right.

In addition, the mother of the king is often mentioned by the Bible. Here is a [list.](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh%2FProphets%2FI%20Kings%7CTanakh%2FProphets%2FII%20Kings%7CTanakh%2FWritings&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance)