# What is the official title for the wife of a Jewish king?

Tags: women, malchut-royalty

The **Rambam** in [Hilchos Melachim U'Milchamot 1:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.1.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes:

> אֵין מַעֲמִידִין אִשָּׁה בְּמַלְכוּת שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים יז טו) "עָלֶיךָ מֶלֶךְ" וְלֹא מַלְכָּה.
>
> We may not appoint a woman to the kingship. As it says, “upon yourselves a king” (Deut. 17:15) - ie a “*king*” and not a “queen”

While this explicitly teaches that we can't **appoint** a woman to royalty, **what if her husband is king?** **By extension, would this mean that her title is now "queen?"**
<sub>(feels like it could be tricky to call her that- there could hypothetically be **18 queens** concurrently?!)</sub>

Comment: not really related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68918/what-powers-and-responsibilities-do-wives-of-jewish-kings-have-in-relation-to-th

Comment: What was עתליה called ?

Comment: @sam אם חזקיה, interestingly enough. She’s never given a royal title.

Comment: Though the passuk says עתליה מלכת(mo'leches)

Answer (score 4):

I’m aware of two terms used in Tanach: either calling her מלכה anyway, as in אסתר המלכה (Esther 5:2-3, 7:1-3, etc.), or the more crass term שגל, “royal consort” (Tehillim 45:10 and Nechemiah 2:6, as interpreted by the conclusion of Rosh Hashanah 4a).

Comment: Also Vashti the Queen

Comment: @DoubleAA right but Esther and Vashti weren't married to Jewish kings

Comment: It appears that each king has his mother's name given rather than mentioning who the king (his father) married. When King David married a woman, she is just referred to as "wife of the king" and not by a special term such as *malka*

Comment: @DoubleAA Given that Vashti personally was royalty I wasn’t sure how much of a proof that was. Esther, while descended from royalty, wasn’t personally royal before she married Achashveirosh.

Comment: @sabbahillel Or occasionally by their son’s name (ex. Bas Sheva mother of Shlomo; Athaliah mother of Chizkiya).

Comment: The OP was discussing what the wife of a JEWISH king was called. Esther was the queen of Persia.

Comment: The term שגל for a queen may not be crass. See [here](https://jewish-faculty.biu.ac.il/files/jewish-faculty/shared/JSIJ2/pinker.pdf), p. 179ff.

Comment: It's a bit later, but Josephus and other folks(like the population of Judea) didn't seem to have a terminology problem with Salome/Shelamtzion the ruling queen.

Answer (score 3):

Easy.

שיר השירים פרק ו פסוק ח

> שִׁשִּׁים הֵמָּה **מְלָכוֹת**, וּשְׁמֹנִים פִּילַגְשִׁים; וַעֲלָמוֹת,
>   אֵין מִסְפָּר

This verse talks about the king's spouses, and the word is מלכה (queen).