# Who are the descendants of King David today?

Tags: messiah, genealogy, king-david

Since the Messiah should come from the line of David, I think it is necessary to know the family line of a person who claims to be the Messiah.

Do we still have the descendants of King David today?

Is it possible to identify the Messiah without knowing his family line?

Comment: There are people who know that they are descendants of certain descendants of King David.

Comment: IINM there's a book that lists all the descendants of King David, down to the modern day....if I find the title I'll post an answer.

Comment: http://www.jpost.com/Jewish-World/Jewish-Features/Are-you-a-descendant-of-the-House-of-David

Comment: http://www.jewishgen.org/Rabbinic/journal/descent.htm

Comment: I'm a direct descendant from the Maharal of Prague, who in turn was a direct descendant of King Dovid.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your last question first, logic dictates that when someone comes who fulfills all the requirements of the Mashiach, then we will know that he is of the line of Zerubavel.

Rambam Hilchos Melachim (Chapter 11)

Halacha 1 starts

> 1. In future time, the King Moshiach [1] will arise and **renew the Davidic dynasty**, restoring it to its initial sovereignty. He will
>      rebuild the [Beis Ha]Mikdash and gather in the dispersed remnant of
>      Israel. Then, in his days, all the statutes will be reinstituted as in
>      former times. We will offer sacrifices and observe the Sabbatical and
>      Jubilee years according to all their particulars set forth in the
>      Torah.

Also, if Eliyahu hanavi comes first, he will testify as to who he is. However, this should not be needed since the Rambam includes "renewing the Davidic dynasty" as part of his accomplishments. This can only be done if he is a member of that dynasty.

As to your first question, I discuss it at [which kings must Moshiach descend from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/which-kings-must-moshiach-descend-from/37097#37097)

> There is a web site that discusses the lines of descent from Zerubavel
>   through the ages.
>
> [Descendants of Zerubavel Rashei Galut (Exilarchs), Gaonim and Rabbis.](http://www.davidicdynasty.org/descendants-of-zerubavel/)
>
> The page is too big to copy here, so just follow the link.
>
> Descendants of Zerubavel, great-grandson of the last king of the
>   Davidic Monarchy
>
> There are many versions of these lines of descent. The principal ones
>   are shown here:
>
> 1)Ibn Yachya (Don Yechia), Charlap – “The Book of Destiny – Toledot
>   Charlap” – 1996 Arthur F. Menton.
>
> Drawn from fifteen family trees researched by the author.
>
> See explanations under “What the Experts Say, Articles”.
>
> http://davidicdynasty.org/the-book-of-destiny-chapter-xxvi/
>
> http://davidicdynasty.org/the-book-of-destiny-chapter-xxv/
>
> 2) Ibn Yachya (Don Yechia), Charlap – “Sefer Kidushei” Avraham Moshe
>   Hamburger.
>
> 3) “Makor Niftakh LeBeit David” – 1969, Moshe Yair Weinstok.
>
> 4) Dayan – “Yashir Moshe”, 1864, Moshe Dayan.
>
> 5) Abarbanel – undated handwritten manuscript from the collection of
>   the late Rabbi Shmuel Gorr, held by Chaim Freedman.
>
> Reference was made to “Elef Margaliot” 1993, Meir Wunder.
>
> Several websites have differing versions, such as
>
> http://www.loebtree.com/early.html
>
> Ongoing research may be reflected in future alterations to the chart.
>
> http://www.loebtree.com/rashi.html
>   ** Traditional descent of the Maharal of Prague from Yehudah Liwai Hazaken is challenged by several researchers and requires further
>   study.
>
> (Englard – “Tzfunot” 12, quoted by Rosenstein, “Avotaynu Volume XII,
>   Number 1, Spring 1996, reprinted in Englard’s  “ Letoldot Kheker
>   Hayukhsin Beyisrael” 2004). )

Comment: How do you know no one else will come first and do those things? The Rambam says [if they are mashiach then they do X not if someone does X then they are mashiach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent). (I exclude renew the _Davidic_ dynasty because that is tautological. Someone could possibly establish a non-Davidic dynasty temporarily, as the Chasmonaim did.)