# Was the Lubavitcher Rebbe a descendant of Dovid HaMelech?

Tags: messiah, chabad, genealogy, king-david, messianism

Some Chabad chassidim believe the late Lubavitcher Rebbe, Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson, was and is the Moshiach. (This is a subject that has been addressed already on this SE.)

My question is, a prerequisite for the Moshiach is that he must be a descendant of Dovid HaMelech. If the Lubavitcher Rebbe was not a descendant of him, then that would cut down any further argument for Chabad Messianism.

So, was Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson, the Lubavitcher Rebbe, a descendant of Dovid HaMelech?

**Edit**: The Moshiach must be a descendant of Dovid HaMelech paternally (ie, running through the father). Thus, I want sources proving or disproving the Rebbe's connection with King David through his father.

Comment: I'm almost positive I've seen a few pilpulim in http://haoros.com/ . Can't find it now, though :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic

Comment: The question you are really asking is if the Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson has inheritance rights through his paternal line to the house of King David. Most people don't follow the details of this clearly and say the Rebbe is descended via the Alter Rebbe to the Maharal of Prague. The Rebbe's paternal line is via the Tzemach Tzedek whose father was Rabbi Shalom Shachna Altschuler, son of Rabbi Noach Altschuler. Shalom Shachne was married to Devorah Leah, the Alter Rebbe's 2nd daughter. The question is about the yichus of Rabbi Noach Altschuler.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The Maharal's yichus to Dovid HaMelech is also kind of unclear

Comment: @ShmuelBrin as is anyone's from the last five hundred years, and possibly much more than that.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I've seen people who question it based upon the inscriptions on his tzion. It's above my pay grade to question the yichus of the Maharal. I'm sure if it is required, the issue will be clarified. I was fortunate a couple of years ago to obtain a copy of the sefer yuchasin manuscript of someone from Beit David showing each generation from Rav Eliezer Mintz up until WW II. Rav Mintz, father of Rabbi Yehudah Mintz, was a descendent of Rashi who was the 33rd generation from Yochanan HaSandlar, who was descended from Beit David.

Comment: @YaacovDeane **a descendent of Rashi** Rashi had sons?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin It doesn't indicate in the sefer yuchasin how Rav Eliezer Mintz is descended from Rashi. There is a 250 year gap. It could be via a paternal line uncle of Rashi for example. In which case, the same yichus Rashi claims would apply to Rav Mintz. Rashi claims yichus to Rabbi Yochanan HaSandlar.

Comment: While everyone here is mumbling about Ashkenazim, the stronger Davidic traditions are out in the Syrian community. related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47696/759

Comment: An excellent article discussing the subject of descended from King David...http://www.momentmag.com/king-davids-genes-2/

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I just started reviewing the Sefer Yuchasin of Rabbi Ephraim Margoliyot. I have to read it more carefully, but he seems to be listing a son for Rashi. Bli neder, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin According to ספר מעלות היוחסין by Rabbi Ephraim Eliezer Margaliyot, on page 63 it states that Rashi had two sons. The eldest was Elyakim who moved to Germany and the younger was Yechiel. It says Yechiel had a son who was a doctor and was named Shlomo after his grandfather. That would mean after Rashi's petirah. Shlomo HaRofeh had a son named Amitav who moved to Vienna.

Comment: There is a sefer that contains his entire yichus for 40 generations. I was given a copy and will post it here if I manage to remember. According to this record, he is indeed a direct paternal descendant of Dovid Hamelech as well as many, many other greats

Comment: @SAH - Really? I'd be interested in seeing that sefer.

Comment: @ezra Yeah, it's fascinating, although I don't know that the list is proof. The rest of the sefer may contain proof

Comment: @SAH - It would still be fascinating, even if the info contained therein needed more research and proof.

Comment: OK, this is interesting: https://www.familytreedna.com/public/yichus

Comment: (The link above undoubtedly needs to be taken with its own grain of salt...)

Comment: @SAH - That link pretty much says there are no kohanim either, so...

Comment: @ezra Yeah I don't exactly buy it; they don't bring much evidence, and they have an agenda. But the same could perhaps be said of my "proof"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer I received for this question. There isn't anything that proves 100% that the Lubavitcher Rebbe's lineage can be traced back to Dovid Hamelech as I would think it is doubtful anyone today could trace their lineage back that far, but here is the reasoning behind this claim which was not as I thought through the Maharal...

There is speculation that the Tzemach Tzedek's father, Reb Shalom Shachna, was a direct descendant of the Metzudas Dovid, who in turn was a direct descendant of Dovid Hamelech. This isn't 100% proven, but that's the closest it gets.

All the best,

Rabbi Eliezer Zalmanov
for Chabad.org

Comment: http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=872&cat=11&haoro=1

Comment: I am going to go ahead and mark this answer accepted, although I would be interested in seeing how the Metzudas Dovid was a direct descendant of Dovid HaMelech. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

יחוס הרבי מליובאוויטש עד לדוד המלך
תקופת מלכי ישראל בבית ראשון א. דוד המלך. ב. שלמה המלך. ג. רחבעם המלך. ד. אביהו המלך. ה. אסא המלך. ו. יהושפט המלך. ז. יהורם המלך. ח. אחזיהו המלך. ט. יהואש המלך י. אמציהו המלך. יא. עוזיהו המלך. יב. יותם המלך. יג. אחז המלך. יד. חזקיהו המלך. טו. מנשה המלך. טז. אמון המלך יז. יאשיהו המלך. יח. יהויקים המלך. יט. יכניהו המלך. כ. השר שאלתיאל.
תקופת בית המקדש השני    כא. פדיה. כב. זרובבל. כג. משולם. כד. חנניה. כה. ברכיה. כו. חסדיה. כז. ישעיה. כח. עובדיה. כט. שכניה. ל. שמעיה. לא. נעריה.
תקופת ריש גלותא (תקופת תנאים ואמוראים)  לב. חזקיה ריש גלותא. לג. התנא עוקבן בר נחמיה - נתן דצוציתא ריש גלותא. לד. ר' הונא ריש גלותא. לה. ר' עקוב ריש גלותא. לו. ר' נחום ריש גלותא. לז. ר' יוחנן ריש גלותא. לח. ר' שפט ריש גלותא. לט. ר' ענן ריש גלותא. מ. ר' הונא ריש גלותא. מא. ר' נתן ריש גלותא. מב. ר' נחמיה ריש גלותא. מג. ר' עוקבן דצוציתא ריש גלותא. מד. ר' אבא ריש גלותא. מה. ר' ספרא ריש גלותא. מו. מר זוטרא ריש גלותא. מז. רב כהנא ריש גלותא. מח. רב גוריא ריש גלותא. מט. מר בוסתנאי ריש גלותא. נ. רב יעקב ריש גלותא. נא. רב מגיס ריש גלותא. נב. רב נחמיה ריש גלותא. נג. רב אבדימא ריש גלותא. נד. רב פינחס ריש גלותא. נה. רב חצוב ריש גלותא.
תקופת הגאונים   נו. רב שמואל גאון. נז. רב יהודה גאון. נח. רב חנניה גאון. נט. רב שרירא גאון. ס. רב האי גאון.
תקופת ראשונים ואחרונים  סא. הרה"ג ר' יוסף מרומי. סב. הרה"ג ר' יחיאל. סג. הרה"ג ר' אברהם. סד. הרה"ג ר' עזריהו. סה. הרה"ג ר' יחזקאל. סו. הרה"ג ר' לעמיל. סז. הרה"ג ר' עזריהו. סח. הרה"ג ר' אליהו. סט. הרה"ג ר' יוסף. ע. הרה"ג ר' נחמן. עא. הרה"ג ר' קלמן קלונימוס. עב. הרה"ג ר' לייביש. עג. הרה"ג ר' אלעזר. עד. הרה"ג ר' ירחמיאל. עה. הרה"ג ר' אריה זאב. עו. הרה"ג ר' יעקב. עז. הרה"ג ר' בצלאל. עח. הרה"ג ר' יהודה ליוואי – המהר"ל הזקן. עט. הרה"ג ר' בצלאל. פ. הרה"ג ר' חיים מוורמייזא. פא. הרה"ג ר' בצלאל.
מהמהר"ל לאבי אדמו"ר הזקן    פב. הרה"ג מרנא ורבנא יהודה ליוואי – המהר"ל מפראג. פג. הרה"ג ר' בצלאל חריף. פד. הרה"ג ר' שמואל. פה.הרה"ג ר' יהודה לייב. פו. הרה"ג ר' משה מפוזנא. פז. הרה"ג ר' שניאור זלמן. פח. הרה"ג ר' ברוך.
תקופת נשיאי חב"ד    פט. כ"ק אדמו"ר הזקן. צ. הרבנית דבורה לאה (בת אדמו"ר הזקן). צא. כ"ק אדמו"ר הצמח צדק. צב. רבי ברוך שלום שניאורסון (בן הצמח צדק). צג. רבי לוי יצחק שניאורסון (נכד הצמח צדק). צד. רבי ברוך שניאור זלמן שניאורסון (סב אדמו"ר שליט"א). צה. הרב המקובל רבי לוי יצחק שניאורסון (אב אדמו"ר שליט"א). צו. כ"ק אדמו"ר רבי מנחם מנדל שניאורסון שליט"א.

רבותינו נשיאינו שייכים לדוד המלך, הן מצד ענין הנשיאות בכלל ששייך לדוד המלך, והן מצד זה שאדמו"ר הזקן הוא מזרע דוד המלך, ולכן יש לרבותינו נשיאינו ניצוץ של דוד המלך, והם ממלאי מקומו.[1]

הרבי הרש"ב העיד על עצמו ועל אדמו"רי חב"ד בשיחתו שהם מזרע דוד - וזה לשונו הקדוש (מאידיש): "שלא יכבה נרו לעולם ועד, כי אור הבעל שם טוב מאיר תמיד, חסידות תהיה בלי ספק עד משיח, שהרי דוד מלך ישראל חי וקיים, שזה היה הבעל שם טוב, והמגיד (ממעזריטש), והרבי (אדמו"ר הזקן), וכן הלאה (אדמו"רי חב"ד), שהרי אנחנו מזרע דוד, וזה ימשיך הלאה עד משיח".[2]

עובדה זו זוכה להדגשה מיוחדת לאור העיסוק בזהותו של הרבי כמלך המשיח, שאחד מסימניו של מלך המשיח הוא "מלך מבית דוד"[3], כלומר צאצא של דוד המלך. תנאי זה מתקיים ברבי ובשאר רבותינו נשיאנו, כדבריו[4]: "רבותינו נשיאנו, שהינם מיוחסים לבית דוד משבט יהודה".

[http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/תבנית:שלשלת_יחוס_המשיח](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA:%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97)

The following mechkar was written by הרב שלום דובער הלוי וולפא, בית משיח regarding the yichus of the Rebbe to Dovid HaMelech both ben achar ben and ben achar bas:

הרבי מיוחס לדוד המלך: גם בן אחר בן וגם בן אחר בת

ועל פי זה עולה שבכ"ק אדמו"ר הצ"צ היו ב' המעלות, כי היה מהזכרים דבית דוד מצד אביו, ובנוסף לזה היתה בו מעלה יתירה שהיה נכד אדמו"ר הזקן. ובזה גופא מצד אמו דוקא, ובכך יש מעלה נוספת על היותו בן אחר בן מדוד "ויצא חוטר מגזע ישי" ● ואם-כן בכ"ק אדמו"ר שליט"א יש את ב' המעלות, שהוא בן אחר בן למלכות דוד – מסבו הצ"צ, וגם בן אחר הבת למלכות דוד – מסבו אדמוה"ז ● מאמר מאלף אודות יחוסו של הרבי מלך המשיח לדוד המלך - גם בן אחר בן, וגם בן אחר בת ● מאת הרב שלום דובער וולפא באדיבות מגזין 'בית משיח' ● לקריאה

א

הרבי הרש"ב מעיד: אנחנו מזרע דוד

בסה"ש תשמ"ט ע' 650 (מאידיש): "היחוס של בעל ההילולא (הרה"ק ר' לוי יצחק זי"ע, אביו של כ"ק אדמו"ר מה"מ) הוא מזרע דוד. כידוע שהוא דור השביעי מאדמו"ר הזקן, שהוא דור השביעי מהמהר"ל מפראג, והמהר"ל מיוחס לזרע דוד". ומציין בהערה ל"תורת שלום" ע' 176 שכ"ק אדמו"ר מוהרש"ב נ"ע מעיד על עצמו ועל אדמור"י חב"ד שהם מזרע דוד: וזלה"ק (מאידיש): "שלא יכבה נרו לעולם ועד, כי אור הבעל שם טוב מאיר תמיד, חסידות תהיה בלי ספק עד משיח, שהרי דוד מלך ישראל חי וקיים, שזה היה הבעל שם טוב, והמגיד (ממעזריטש), והרבי (אדמו"ר הזקן), וכן הלאה (אדמו"רי חב"ד), שהרי אנחנו מזרע דוד, וזה ימשיך הלאה עד משיח". ועוד שם (ע' ‎235-6‏): "הרי בחרו בנו הבוחר בדוד ובזרעו אחריו.. ה' יעזור שזה יהיה לעד". ואותו היחוס בדיוק הוא להרה"ק רבי לוי יצחק, שהוא דור רביעי בן אחר בן לכ"ק אדמו"ר בעל הצמח צדק.

ויש השואלים, דהן אמת שאדמו"ר הזקן היה מבית דוד, אבל לכאורה אדמו"ר הצ"צ היה בן בתו של אדמוה"ז וחתן אדמו"ר האמצעי. ועל פי זה גם כ"ק אדמו"ר מה"מ שהוא דור חמישי לצ"צ, יחוסו הוא על-ידי אם הצ"צ, והרי כתב הרמב"ם בפ"א ממלכים שדוד זכה בכתר מלכות רק לבניו הזכרים. ואם-כן מי שייחוסו מנקבות בית דוד לא יורש לכאורה את מלכות דוד אביו.

אלא שלמרות שאלה זו, הרי עדותו הברורה של כ"ק אדמו"ר מוהרש"ב מוכיחה, או שגם בן הבת יורש את מלכות דוד, או שגם רבי שלום שכנא זצ"ל אביו של הצמח צדק היה מבית דוד (או ששני הדברים נכונים, וכדלקמן).

ויש להוסיף ע"פ דברי הרמב"ם ב"אגרת תימן": "והאותות והמופתים שיראו על ידו הן הן הראיות על אמיתת יחוסו". הרי שאף על פי שלגבי עצם הסימנים של משיח, אין צריך לשאול ממנו אותות ומופתים כמבואר בהלכות מלכים (פי"א ה"ג), אבל לענין זה של יחוסו למלכות בית דוד, הנה האותות והמופתים שעושה הן הן הראיות על אמיתת ייחוסו.

וזה ידוע, שאין לנו בדורנו עוד תופעה מופלאה כזו של אותות ומופתים שלמעלה מדרך הטבע לגמרי, אשר נעשים על ידי כ"ק אדמו"ר שליט"א, כמעשים בכל יום במשך למעלה מששים שנה. וכל מי שהיה לו פעם קשר כלשהו עם ליובאוויטש, יכול לספר מה ש"בדידו הוי עובדא", על ישועה פלאית בעניני הכלל והפרט, שהגיעה לו על-ידי ברכתו של צדיק הדור, או הוראות נפלאות בגשמיות ורוחניות "כאשר ישאל איש באלקים", ודברי עתידות "קולע אל השערה". ואם-כן "הן הן הראיות על אמיתת יחוסו".

ובכל זאת מן הראוי לברר סוגיא זו עד כמה שאפשר, בכדי לספק גם את אלו שבנוסף לאמונתם בדברי הצדיקים החיים וקיימים לעד, רצונם להבין כל דבר גם על פי השכל ולמצוא לזה מקורות בהלכה.

ב

אדמו"ר הזקן – בן אחר בן, עד לדוד המלך

והנה הרה"צ רבי שלום שכנא אביו של הצ"צ, היה בנו של הרה"ח רבי נח מתלמידי כ"ק הרמ"מ מוויטעבסק, מצאצאי משפחת אלטשולר שהתיחסו לבעל ה"מצודות דוד" שמייחסים אותו לדוד המלך (ויש אומרים שרבי שלום שכנא היה גם מצאצאי הגאון רבי שכנא רבו של הרמ"א ונקרא על שמו, ובשמות גיטין לה"בית שמואל" אבהע"ז סימן קכט, כתב שהגאון רבי שכנא ז"ל נתן סימן על עצמו שהוא המשיח שנאמר "לשכנו תדרשו", כי שכנא הוא לשון שכינה. ובשו"ת הרמ"א מביא שבנו של רבי שכנא כותב עליו: "רוח אפינו משיח ה'.. נשיא ישראל").

וגם לולא שידענו את היחוס המדויק, הרי עצם הדבר שאדמוה"ז לקח את רבי שלום שכנא לבתו מרת דבורה לאה, ואחר-כך לקח אדמו"ר האמצעי את הצ"צ כחתן לבתו מרת חיה מושקא, ובפרט כאשר ברור ששני צדיקי עולם אלו ידעו ברוח קדשם שהצ"צ ימשיך את שושלת בית המלך דליובאוויטש, הרי זה עצמו מעיד שרבי שלום שכנא ובנו הצ"צ היו אף הם מזרע דוד מבית המלוכה (וכמבואר בכתובות סב, ב. בענין הקפדתו של רבינו הקדוש לקחת לבנו אשה ממלכות דוד, ואם-כן כל-שכן שכן הוא בלקיחת חתן שממנו תמשיך שושלת המלוכה).

ושמעתי מש"ב הגה"ח ר' שמואל היילפרין ז"ל, שקיבל מהגה"ח רבי משה לייב שפירא זצ"ל ראש ישיבת תורת אמת, בשם זקני החסידים בדור שלפניו, שהיה מקובל אצלם אשר כ"ק אדמוה"ז הוא מבית דוד מנוקבתא, ודוקא הצ"צ הוא מבית דוד מדכורא.

אבל במסורת זו נצטרך לכאורה לומר "פלגינן דיבוריה". כי זה שאמרו שאדמוה"ז הוא מנוקבתא דבית דוד טעון בדיקה, דאם הכוונה לסדר יחוסו למהר"ל מפראג, שכאילו אינו בן אחר בן מהמהר"ל, הרי ידוע שאמנם בספר "בית רבי" בתחילתו כתב, שהגאון רבי יהודה לייב (אבדק"ק קאוולי בעל "קול יהודה", שהיה אביו זקנו של רבי ברוך זצ"ל אביו של אדמו"ר הזקן) – היה נינו של חתן המהר"ל רבי יוסף יאסקי אבדק"ק לובלין. ועל פי זה הרי אדמוה"ז הוא מבתו של המהר"ל. אבל בספר "היום יום" (ובמכתב כ"ק אדמו"ר הריי"צ באג"ק ח"ח, ב'תצו) מפורש, שרבי יהודה לייב הנ"ל היה בנו של רבי שמואל, בנו של רבי בצלאל, בן המהר"ל.

ולהעיר מהמסופר ב"ספר הזכרונות" פצ"א, שרבי משה אביו של רבי שניאור זלמן, אביו של רבי ברוך, אביו של אדמוה"ז, נשא לאשה את "שרה בתו היתומה של רבי שניאור זלמן שהיה מגזע היחס של רבי יצחק כ"ץ חתנו של המהר"ל. וכך נקשרו הקצוות של שני ענפי משפחת המהר"ל – צאצאי בנו היחיד וצאצאי בתו". ואם-כן שתי המסורות נכונות, שאדמוה"ז היה מגזע המהר"ל מדכורא בן אחר בן, וגם מנוקבתא על-ידי חתנו (אבל אין זה אותו החתן המוזכר ב"בית רבי". ובקובץ "יגדיל תורה" ניו יורק שנה עשירית חוברת ע"א ע' רמב ואילך, הוכיח הרה"ח ר' שד"ב לוין שי', שהאמור ב"בית רבי" בענין זה אינו נכון, וביסס את האמור ב"היום יום" על-פי מחקרים היסטוריים).

ועל פי זה הרי מסורת הנ"ל שאדמוה"ז הוא מנקבות דבית דוד אינה ביחוסו למהר"ל. אבל יתכן שהכוונה ליחוסו של המהר"ל עצמו, שנאמר עליו (ב"היום יום" שם ובמגילה היוחסין שלו), שהיה: "מגזע הגאונים המיוחסים לדוד בן ישי", שיחוס זה עצמו יכול להיות מנוקבתא. אבל גם זה אינו נכון וכבר נעשתה עבודת מחקר נפלאה על פי ספרי יחס קדמונים, ע"י הרה"ח ר' יוסף סולומון מכפר חב"ד, ובה יחוס מפורט של 82 דורות בן אחר בן מדוד המלך עד המהר"ל בשמותיהם לדורותיהם.

ג

אדמו"ר הצמח-צדק – גם בן אחר בן, וגם בן הבת

ואם-כן ברור, שמקורה של מסורת זו שאדמוה"ז הוא מנוקבתא דבית דוד, הוא ביחוס המוטעה שבספר "בית רבי" וכנ"ל, אבל על כל פנים את זה נקבל ממסורת זו שמסר הגרמ"ל שפירא, שגם כ"ק הצ"צ היה מדכורא דבית דוד. וזה מתאים להמסופר אודות הטעם שכ"ק אדמו"ר האמצעי נקרא בשם זה "האמצעי", כי בזמן מלכותו של הצ"צ היו החסידים שבדורו בטוחים בלי ספק שהוא המשיח "מנחם שמו" (ומבאר הרבי שלכן קראו ספרו בשם "צמח צדק"), ובמילא הוא הנשיא האחרון, וחותנו הנשיא השני הוא ה"אמצעי", וכך נשאר תוארו לדורות.

ועל פי זה עולה שבכ"ק אדמו"ר הצ"צ היו ב' המעלות, כי היה מהזכרים דבית דוד מצד אביו, ובנוסף לזה היתה בו מעלה יתירה שהיה נכד אדמו"ר הזקן. ובזה גופא מצד אמו דוקא, ובכך יש מעלה נוספת על היותו בן אחר בן מדוד, וכמבואר במכתב כ"ק אדמו"ר מוהריי"צ (מיום ו' אייר תרצ"ט – אג"ק ח"ד א'ק, ו"היום יום" כ"ח אייר), שביום השלושים להסתלקות כ"ק אדמוה"ז זכה כ"ק הצ"צ לראות את זקנו בחזיון לילה, ולמד עמו הסוגיא בפרק יש נוחלין (קי, ב) ששאלו בגמרא שם עה"פ למען ירבו ימיכם וימי בניכם, "אי הכי נמי בניכם ולא בנותיכם", ותירצו "ברכה שאני". ואחר כך אמר לו כ"ק אדמו"ר הזקן: "איש מזריע תחילה יולדת נקבה, זו היא אמך. אשה מזרעת תחילה יולדת זכר, זה הוא אתה".

שבזה נראה שביחוסו של הצ"צ לאדמוה"ז יש אדרבה מעלה בכך שהוא בן הבת, וכפי שמצינו גם בהלכה למעשה שהבת מקבלת תכונות אביה יותר מהבן (רמ"א או"ח סימן קכ"ח סמ"א, ומג"א סקס"ב, ופרמ"ג בא"א שם). וראה לקו"ש ח"ח ע' 165 בלשון רש"י ר"פ פנחס "פיטם אבי אמו עגלים לע"ז", כי בן הבת מקבל תכונות הסב יותר מבן הבן.

ואם-כן בכ"ק אדמו"ר שליט"א יש את ב' המעלות, שהוא בן אחר בן למלכות דוד – מסבו הצ"צ, וגם בן אחר הבת למלכות דוד – מסבו אדמוה"ז.

ד

איך אמרו על רבינו הקדוש שהוא משיח?

ויש לבאר בעומק יותר את הטעם שבמשיח יש את שני היחוסים הנ"ל מבן ומבת. דהנה ידוע, שמיסוד האמונה בביאת המשיח הוא ש"לא יסור שבט מיהודה", ועוד שהמשיח יהיה מזרע דוד ושלמה דוקא. וכמפורש בסהמ"צ ל"ת מצוה שס"ב: "אמנם המלכות לבד, כבר ידעת מכתובי ספרי הנבואה שזכה בה דוד.. וכן זרעו אחריו עד סוף כל הדורות. אין מלך למי שיאמין תורת משה רבינו ע"ה אדון כל הנביאים, אלא מזרע דוד ומזרע שלמה לבד. וכל מי שהוא מזולת זה הזרע הנכבד, לענין מלכות נכרי קרינן ביה, כמו שכל מי שהוא מזולת זרע אהרן, לענין עבודה זר קרינא ביה. וזה מבואר אין ספק בו", ועל דרך זה בפיה"מ פרק חלק ביסוד השנים עשר: "ומכלל יסוד זה, שאין מלך לישראל אלא מבית דוד ומזרע שלמה בלבד. וכל החולק על המשפחה הזאת כפר בשם השם ית' ובדברי נביאיו" (ומקורו בתנחומא ס"פ תולדות).

ומש"כ הרמב"ם שמצאנו זה "בכתובי ספרי הנבואה", הוא בדברי הימים (א' כב, ט-י, ועוד) שדוד המלך הובטח ע"י הקב"ה "הנה בן נולד לך.. שלמה יהיה שמו.. והכינותי את כסא מלכותו על ישראל עד עולם". וכמבואר בשיחות כ"ק אדמו"ר מה"מ, שהנצחיות של מלכות דוד היא דוקא על ידי זה שהמלכות עוברת דרך בנו שלמה, ולכן הכריזה בת שבע "יחי אדוני המלך דוד לעולם" רק אחרי שדוד הבטיח ששלמה בנו ימלוך אחריו.

ועל פי זה צריך להבין את המבואר בסנהדרין צח, ב: "אמר רב, אי מן חייא הוא (מלך המשיח) כגון רבינו הקדוש. אי מן מתייא הוא כגון דניאל איש חמודות". ופירש"י בלישנא קמא דמה שאמרו "כגון" הוא לאו דוקא, אלא שאכן "אם משיח מאותן שחיים עכשיו ודאי היינו רבינו הקדוש דסובל תחלואים וחסיד גמור הוה". ונשאלת קושיא עצומה, איך אמרו שרבינו הקדוש הוא המשיח, והרי מפורש בכתובות סב, ב. דיחוסו של רבי הוא משפטיה בן אביטל (אשת דוד), ולא מזרע שלמה.

וביותר קשה מהמבואר בירושלמי כתובות פי"ב ה"ג וכלאים פ"ט ה"ג, ומובא בתוס' סנהדרין ה, א. ד"ה דהכא שבט והתם מחוקק, דיחוסו של רבינו הקדוש לבית דוד הוא רק מצד האם, אבל מאביו הוא מבנימין. ואם-כן לא זו בלבד שאינו מזרע שלמה, אלא שכלל אינו משבט יהודה ובמילא אין לו משפט המלוכה, וכדכתיב "לא יסור שבט מיהודה.. עד כי יבא שילה".

ה

התינוק היחיד שנותר מהזכרים של בית דוד

והנה היעב"ץ בהוריות יא, ב. כתב שלתלמוד הבבלי רבינו הקדוש הוא מנוקבתא דשלמה ומדכורא דשפטיה, והיינו שהיה בן אחר בן מדוד באמצעות שפטיה בן אביטל, ובנוסף לזה היה גם מזרע שלמה מנוקבתא. ואם-כן הוא משבט יהודה וגם מזרע שלמה, אף שאינו בן אחר בן מדוד ושלמה. אבל צ"ע אם אפשר לומר כן, שהרי בכתובות שם אמרו: "רבי איעסק ליה לבריה (להשיאו) בי רבי חייא, כי מטא למיכתב כתובה נח נפשה דרביתא (מתה הכלה, בתו של ר' חייא). אמר רבי: ח"ו פסולא איכא? יתיבו ועיינו במשפחות (ומצאו:) רבי אתי משפטיה בן אביטל, ורבי חייא אתי משמעי אחי דוד", ופירש"י: "אביטל שם אשת דוד, ור' חייא אתי משמעי, וזהו הפסול שרבי היה מבית דוד ולא היתה בת הבאה משמעי הוגנת לבנו שלא היתה בת מלכים". ומוכח מכאן שרבי אינו משלמה, דאם-כן היה לגמרא לומר שבח גדול יותר דרבי אתי אף משלמה, ולא תיפסק המלכות מצאצאיו. ועל- כרחך שאינו מזרע שלמה, ומה שאמרו בירושלמי שרבי בא מנוקבתא, היינו מנוקבתא דשפטיה, ואינו משבט יהודה כלל.

ועוד קשה, איך יתכן שרבי היה מזכרים דשפטיה, והרי עתליה בת אחאב הרגה את כל זרע המלוכה, ולא השאירה מן הזכרים שריד ופליט, חוץ מהתינוק יואש בן אחזיה, מבני בניו של שלמה, שהתחבא עם מניקתו בקדש הקדשים (מלכים ב' פי"א, וסנהדרין צה, ב). ואם-כן איך יתכן שיהיה מישהו בדורות מאוחרים יותר שיתייחס לזכרים דשפטיה. ועיין בספר "רמתים צופים" זוטא פכ"א (להרה"ק ר' שמואל משינאווא) שכתב: "משמע כי חוץ מיואש לא נשתייר אחד, והרי אמרו דרבי אתיא משפטיה בן אביטל. נראה לומר כי היא הרגה רק את הזכרים ולא את הנקבות, וכן מוכח בירושלמי, אנא מן נוקבתא".

ו

רבינו הקדוש העיד על עצמו: אני משבט בנימין

והנה למרות כל זאת, הרי החיד"א ב"ברכי יוסף" חו"מ סימן א' אות יו"ד כתב כתירוץ היעב"ץ הנ"ל, והביא את הראב"ד בספר הקבלה, שהלל היה מבני בניו של דוד הזכרים (לשון ספר הקבלה לפנינו, שהלל היה "מבית דוד מזרע המלוכה"), ובמילא רבינו הקדוש שהוא מבני בניו של הלל, אף הוא היה מזכרים דדוד. ועל פי זה מה שאמרו בכתובות שהוא משפטיה, הכוונה מזכרים דשפטיה. אבל קשה לומר דהסוגיא בכתובות חלוקה על הירושלמי. שהרי התוס' סנהדרין הנ"ל בונה מירושלמי זה דינים להלכה.

והברכ"י עצמו שם הביא את הירושלמי, דרבינו הקדוש אומר שרב הונא (ה"ריש גלותא") גדול ממנו, "דהוא מן יהודה ואנא מבנימין, הוא מן דכריה ואנא מנוקבתא". (וע"כ מנוקבתא דשפטיה, כי אם מנוקבתא דשלמה ומדכורא דשפטיה, א"כ אינו מבנימין אלא מיהודה). וכן פירש בפני משה שם: "כלומר שרבי היה ג"כ מיהודה מבית דוד, אלא שרב הונא היה מזכרים מיהודה ורבי מנקבות.. וחשוב הוא (רב הונא) בייחוס ממנו". וכן כתב המאירי בהקדמתו לאבות: "כלומר, שהיתה לאחד מקדומי משפחתו אשה מבני שפטיה בן אביטל, אבל מצד אביו היה משבט בנימין". וחזרה הקושיא איך אמרו על רבינו הקדוש שהוא המשיח.

ז

אשה אינה יכולה למלוך, אך יכולה להעביר ירושת המלוכה

ועוד יש להבין, דאפילו אם נדחוק לומר דלבבלי אתי רבינו הקדוש מבית דוד מצד האב משפטיה ומצד האם משלמה, עדיין יוקשה האם צאצא מנוקבתא יכול לרשת את המלוכה. והמנ"ח מצווה תצ"ז הביא את לשון הרמב"ם בהלכות מלכים פ"א ה"ז דכל הקודם בנחלה קודם לירושת המלוכה, וכתב שעפ"ז יתכן שתיסוב נחלת המלוכה גם לבן בת כאשר אין בן הבן. אמנם בהגה"ה שם מובאת קושיית הר"י פערלא, שבאותה ההלכה כתב הרמב"ם דכיון שנמשח דוד זכה בכתר מלכות והרי המלכות לו ולבניו הזכרים עד עולם. ועפ"ז מוכרח לכאורה שמשיח יהיה בן אחר בן משלמה.

איברא שעל-זה היה אפשר לתרץ, שמש"כ הרמב"ם דהמלכות היא לזכרים, היינו רק שאשה אינה יכולה למלוך, אבל העברת ירושת המלוכה באמצעותה מאביה לבנה, זה אינו מושלל. ולכן אם רבינו הקדוש הוא מזרע דוד ויהודה באמצעות שפטיה וגם מזרע שלמה מנוקבתא, הוא ראוי למלכות. ובגמרא שבת (נו, א): "אמר רב, רבי דאתי מדוד מהפך ודריש בזכותיה דדוד", הרי שגם אם רבי בא מנקבות נקרא "דאתי מדוד".

אמנם אף שכן יש לומר בדוחק, שנצחיות מלכות שלמה שתתגלה במשיח תהיה באמצעות נוקבתא, אבל מה נעשה עם התוס' בשם הירושלמי, והמפורש במאירי, דרבינו הקדוש הוא מנוקבתא דשפטיה ואינו משבט יהודה בכלל ולא מזרע שלמה בפרט, וחזרה הקושיא הכיצד אמרו עליו שהוא המשיח שבדור.

ח

האם רבינו הקדוש רק כדוגמא, או בבחינת משיח בן יוסף?

והרה"ק בעל "מנחת אלעזר" בספרו "דברי תורה" ח"ד אות ו' תירץ: "ובע"כ לומר כפירוש הב' ברש"י שם בזה"ל: לישנא אחרא כגון רבינו הקדוש, כלומר אם יש דוגמתו בחיים היינו רבינו הקדוש, ואם דוגמא הוא למתים היינו כגון דניאל איש חמודות (עכ"ל רש"י ז"ל). היינו שהוא רק דוגמא, ו"כגון״ הוא עיקר בלשונו הנ"ל בגמ', דלאו דוקא רבינו הקדוש (כיון דאינו מזרע שלמה) אלא איש א' הדומה לו בחסידותו וסובל יסורים (כנ"ל), אם יהיה מזרע שלמה הוא ראוי להיות משיח", עכ"ל. אבל עדיין אינו מובן מה נעשה עם לישנא קמא דרש"י.

ובספר "בן יהוידע" לבעל ה"בן איש חי" מבגדד, ביאר את הגמרא באופן אחר: "ומ"ש רב אי מן חייא הוא כגון רבינו הקדוש, ג"כ כוונתו על ניצוץ משיח בן יוסף שיבא בכל דור, ואמר כגון רבינו הקדוש שהיה מזרע דוד מנוקבייא וסבל יסורין רבים". וכוונתו, שהיחוס מנוקבתא לזרע דוד הוא מספיק בכדי להקרא משיח בן יוסף, וכמו שפי' גם לעיל בד"ה א"ר נחמן אי מן חייא הוא כגון אנא, וז"ל: "היתה קבלה בידם כי נצוץ משיח בן יוסף אשר יבא בכל דור בצדיק שבדור יבא בצדיק שהוא מזרע דוד ע"ה, ולכך קוראין אותו בשם כסא דוד. ובא ר' נחמן לומר דאין הכוונה שיהיה בזרע דוד ממש, אלא אפילו כגון אנא שאיני מזרע דוד ורק אשתי בת ריש גלותא היא מזרע דוד, אפשר שנחשב איש זה מזרע דוד, משום בעל כאשתו, ויתגלגל בו נצוץ משיח בן יוסף".

אמנם שני תירוצים אלו אינם מתאימים לכאורה עם דרכו של הרבי מה"מ בכ"מ כשמציין לענין זה בשיחותיו הקדושות, דאכן מה שאמרו על רבינו הקדוש שהוא משיח, אין זו דוגמא בלבד, אלא קביעת מציאות שרבינו הקדוש הוא המשיח שבדור, וכן שהכוונה היא למשיח בן דוד. וא"כ עדיין אינו מובן איך יתכן שמי שאינו משבט יהודה ואינו מזרע שלמה, רק מנוקבתא דשפטיה, יהיה המשיח.

ט

מה ה'סוד' ששמע רבי מבניו של רבי חייא?

ויש לומר, בהקדים סוגית הגמרא בהוריות שם: "בעי מיניה רבי מרבי חייא, כגון אני מהו בשעיר", ופירש"י: "כלומר, נשיאות דידי מי הוא נשיאות מעליא, דאילו הוינא בזמן שבית המקדש קיים, מייתינא שעיר או לא". וענה לו רבי חייא: "הרי צרתך בבבל", והיינו שראש הגולה עומד על גביו (כדאמרו בסנהדרין ה, א: "הכא שבט והתם מחוקק"), ולכן לא מתקיים כאן התנאי שבמשנה הוריות (י, א) "איזהו נשיא, זה מלך.. שאין על גביו אלא ה' אלקיו".

ועפ"ז נשאלת עוד קושיא עצומה על דבריו של רב, שאמר שרבינו הקדוש הוא המשיח, והרי מפורש כאן שאין לו דין מלך, וגם לא יכול להיות לו דין מלך כל זמן שהמינוי של "ריש גלותא" קיים.

והנה בגמרא דידן נאמר ששאל רבי מרבי חייא, ובילקוט (ויקרא רמז תסט) מובא דשאלה זו שאל רבי מרב. ולהעיר, שגם את ההודעה שרבי הוא המשיח, יחסו הן לרב והן לרבי חייא, כי בירושלמי (שבת פט"ז ה"א) מבואר שרבי חייא קרא עליו "רוח אפינו משיח ה'". הרי שלשניהם שאל רבי "כגון אני מהו בשעיר", ושניהם השיבו שאין לו דין מלך, דצרתו בבבל. וא"כ שוב אינו מובן איך אמרו שניהם עליו שהוא המשיח, כאשר אין בו אפילו דיני מלך, וגם לא יכולים להיות לו דיני מלך, דצרתו בבבל.

וביותר יוקשה מסנהדרין לח, א: "יהודה וחזקיה בני רבי חייא, הוו יתבי בסעודתא קמי רבי, ולא הוו קאמרי ולא מידי. אמר להו, אגברו חמרא אדרדקי כי היכי דלימרו מילתא. כיון דאיבסום, פתחו ואמרו, אין בן דוד בא עד שיכלו שני בתי אבות מישראל, ואלו הן, ראש הגולה שבבבל ונשיא שבארץ ישראל.. אמר להם (רבי לבני ר"ח) בני, קוצים אתם מטילים לי בעיני. אמר לו רבי חייא, רבי אל ירע בעיניך, יין ניתן בשבעים אותיות וסוד ניתן בשבעים אותיות, נכנס יין יצא סוד".

ועפ"ז אינו מובן כלל, איך אמרו רבי חייא ורב שרבינו הקדוש הוא המשיח, והרי רבי חייא עצמו הסכים לדברי בניו, שלא רק שהנשיא שבארץ ישראל אינו המשיח, אלא אדרבה, שהתנאי לביאת המשיח הוא שיכלו שני בתי האבות, שאחד מהם הוא הנשיא שבארץ ישראל. ועוד צריך להבין, שלאחר שטען רבי בצדק, שבני רבי חייא מטילים קוצים בעיניו, מפני מה נחה רוחו כששמע מרבי חייא, שדברי בניו נאמרו לאחר שנכנס יין ויצא סוד.

יו"ד

סוד הגאולה – חיבור שני המשיחים

ויש לבאר כל זה בהקדים מה שאמרו חז"ל בפרקי דרבי אליעזר, והובא בתוס' (סוטה יג, א. ד"ה סרח בת אשר), ש"סוד הגאולה" הוא, שהבשורת על יציאת מצרים תבוא בלשון "פקוד פקדתי". ונתבאר בס"ד בספר "יחי המלך המשיח" ע' ק-קא, שה"סוד" המונח בלשון זה הוא חיבור שני המשיחים, יוסף ומשה. כי יוסף הצדיק הוא שהבטיח "פקוד יפקוד", וכאשר משה מתחבר עם יוסף לגאול את עם ישראל, הוא גואל מכחו של יוסף ומכריז בלשונו "פקוד פקדתי". והפקידה היא כפולה, כיון שבאה ע"י חיבור שני המשיחים.

ועיי"ש, שכאשר היה צריך משה למצוא היכן טמנו המצרים את ארונו של יוסף, הלך דוקא לסרח בת אשר, וכמובן מהתוס' שם, דמאחר שהיא ידעה את סוד הגאולה של פקוד פקדתי, במילא בודאי ידעה איך לחבר את יוסף ומשה בפועל. וזהו שאמרה סרח בת אשר "אנכי שלומי אמוני ישראל", וביארו בב"ר (ויגש צד, ט) "אני הוא שהשלמתי נאמן לנאמן" (יוסף שהיה נאמן בבית אדוניו המצרי, ומשה שנאמר עליו בכל ביתי נאמן הוא), שסרח בת אשר חיברה בין שני המשיחים (ועיין "לקוטי לוי יצחק" אגרות ע' תיט, בביאור הטעם שחיבור יוסף ומשה שהביא לגאולה היה ע"י סרח בת אשר דוקא).

והנה יוסף ומשה הם הענין דשבט ומחוקק. דיוסף הוא השליט בכל ארץ מצרים, בחי' ריש גלותא, היינו ענין השבט. ואילו משה הוא נותן התורה, עד שגם הנשיא שבארץ ישראל "הוא העומד תחת משה רבינו" (רמב"ם הלכות סנהדרין פ"א ה"ג), ולכן נקרא משה בשם מחוקק "כי שם חלקת מחוקק ספון" (ברכה לג, כא). ובכדי שתהיה גאולת מצרים, היה מוכרח להיות החיבור דשבט ומחוקק, "ויקח משה את עצמות יוסף עמו".

ולא זו בלבד, אלא ששלימות הגאולה בכניסה לארץ ישראל היתה ע"י יהושע דוקא, שהוא המחבר לאחדים כאחד ממש את יוסף ומשה. כי יהושע היה מזרע יוסף (משבט אפרים, ראה רש"י ברכה לג, יז), וגלגול יוסף ("סדר הדורות" ב"א תפח), ועם זאת היה מקבל יחיד של התורה ממשה "ומסרה ליהושע" (כמבואר בהקדמת הרמב"ם לספר הי"ד).

וכשם שיציאת מצרים היתה ע"י חיבור ב' המשיחים, יוסף ומשה, כן הגאולה העתידה לבוא עכשיו ממש, היא ע"י חיבור שני בתי האבות, שבט ומחוקק, ראש הגולה שבבבל והנשיא שבארץ ישראל, שהם כנגד יוסף ומשה כנ"ל.

יא

עד שתכלה החלוקה של שני בתי אבות מישראל

ויש לומר, שזהו הסוד שיצא כשאגברו חמרא אדרדקי. שבני רבי חייא חידשו דבר נפלא, דאין בן דוד בא עד שתכלה החלוקה של שני בתי אבות מישראל, כיון ששני בתי האבות יתאחדו במשיח צדקנו, שהוא עצמו יהיה השבט והמחוקק המאוחדים יחד. וכמפורש בסה"ש תש"נ ח"ב ע' 557 ואילך, שענין המלכות שבמשיח הוא בחי' "משיח בן יוסף", שיוסף הוא המלך הראשון וממנו נמשך המלכות לדוד, ואילו התורה שמשיח משפיע היא בחי' "משיח בן דוד" שבו. ומלך המשיח הגואל את עם ישראל בפועל מאחד באישיותו את שני הענינים. ולכן לא הזכיר הרמב"ם בהלכות מלכים את ענין משיח בן יוסף, "ומשמע מלשונו שם דהכל נעשה ע"י משיח בן דוד" (לקו"ש חל"ב ע' 185). כי משיח יכלול את שתי הבחינות: "יעמוד מלך" – שבט, ו"הוגה בתורה" – מחוקק.

ואפשר שזהו גם מה שאמר יעקב אבינו: "לא יסור שבט מיהודה ומחוקק מבין רגליו, עד כי יבוא שילה ולו יקהת עמים", כלומר: שבכל הדורות יהיו תמיד שני ממונים: שבט - מלך ושליט מיהודה, ומחוקק - מוסר ומלמד התורה לרבים. אבל כל זה רק "עד כי יבוא שילה ולו יקהת עמים", כי בביאת המשיח יכלו שני בתי האבות, ושניהם יתאחדו במשיח צדקנו עצמו: "שילה" - בגימטריא משה, הו"ע תורתו של משיח, ו"יקהת עמים" - המלוכה על כל האומות.

ויובן בזה מה שנחה דעתו של רבינו הקדוש, כשביאר לו רבי חייא, שהתנאי שאין בן דוד בא עד לביטול הנשיאות שבארץ ישראל, אינו מפני שיש איזה ענין שלילי ח"ו בנשיאות זו, אלא אדרבה ששני בתי האבות שבט ומחוקק מתאחדים במשיח צדקנו, שזהו סוד הגאולה (ועיין ב"יחי המלך המשיח" ע' קנח-ט שנתבאר ענין ה"יין" וה"סוד").

יב

רבינו הקדוש – לא משיח בפועל, אלא 'משיח שבדור'

ובכ"ז נבין איך אמרו על רבינו הקדוש שהוא משיח, אע"פ שהיה משבט בנימין, ורק מנוקבתא דשפטיה ולא משלמה, וגם לא היה לו דין מלך, דצרתו בבבל וכו'.

דהנה השבט והמחוקק הם משיח בן יוסף ומשיח בן דוד כנ"ל. ומבואר בלקוטי הש"ס לאריז"ל (טו,א) "תרין משיחין, משיח בן יוסף מדכורא משיח בן דוד מנוקבתא", והוא כדברי הירושלמי והתוס' בסנהדרין הנ"ל, דראש גולה שבבבל הוא מזכרים ונשיא שבארץ ישראל מנקבות.

וכשאמר רב ד"אם משיח מאותן שחיין עכשיו ודאי היינו רבינו הקדוש", אין הכוונה שרבינו הקדוש יקום ויגאל את עם ישראל, אלא שאם בחינת "משיח בן דוד" נמצאת באחד מאותן שחיין עכשיו, הרי זה רבינו הקדוש. אבל כמובן שהוא עצמו לא יכול להביא הגאולה בפועל, כי עיקר המלכות היא לצרתו שבבבל, ראש הגולה משיח בן יוסף שבא מהזכרים. ורק כשיכלו שני בתי אבות, ויתאחדו שניהם במלך המשיח שיכלול את שני הענינים דשבט ומחוקק, רק אז בן דוד בא בפועל ממש וגואל את עם ישראל.

וזהו שפירש"י: "ודאי היינו רבינו הקדוש דסובל תחלואים וחסיד גמור הוה". שלכאורה אין זה מובן כלל, מדוע נקט דוקא שני סימנים אלו, והרי אדרבה אם רוצה רב לומר שרבינו הקדוש הוא משיח, עליו לחפש בו סימנים של מלכות והנהגה, וכלשון הרמב"ם "יעמוד מלך וכו'" (והסימנים שנתן רש"י הפוכים מענין המלכות). אלא שכאמור לא היתה הכוונה למשיח הגואל בפועל את עם ישראל, אלא ל"משיח בן דוד" שבדור. ובחי' משיח בן דוד אין ענינו תוקף המלוכה, ואדרבה, שביחד עם זה שענינו הוא נשיאות של תורה, כדוד המלך שהיה ראש הסנהדרין (עיין כס"מ בהקדמת הרמב"ם ליד החזקה), הרי הוא סובל תחלואים ונקרא "חיורא (מצורע) דבית רבי", כדוד שהיה נרדף כל ימיו, ונצטרע, וביקש "שועתי אליך ותרפאני". וזהו שהוסיף רש"י ש"חסיד גמור" הוא, היינו כדוד שאמר "שמרה נפשי כי חסיד אני" (תהלים פו) ואחז"ל: "לא חסיד אני, שכל מלכי מזרח ומערב כו' ואני ידי מלוכלכות כו' כדי לטהר אשה לבעלה" (ברכות ד,א). שזהו "חסיד" הפועל לטובת השני במסירות נפש, הגם שהוא היפך ממש מהנהגת המלכות של כל מלכי מזרח ומערב.

יג

במלך המשיח תהיה ההתאחדות של "מלך" ו"רב"

ואף שבודאי גם לרבי היה את ענין המלכות, וכמבואר בחדא"ג מהרש"א לסנהדרין שם (מובא בספר השיחות תשנ"ב ח"א ע' 131 הערה 94): "מאותן הבאים מבני דוד ועדיין היה להם ממשלה גם בגלות.. כגון רבינו הקדוש", אבל מ"מ אין כאן שלימות המלכות דצרתו בבבל כנ"ל, ולהלכה אין הוא נקרא "נשיא זה מלך". ולהעיר עוד מספר השיחות תנש"א שיחת ש"ק תזריע מצורע ע' 496, שמצטט שם לשון רש"י "אם משיח מאותן שחיין עכשיו", וכותב בהערה 66: "וע"פ פס"ד הרמב"ם.. ואם יעמוד מלך מבית דוד כו' – היינו שהוא כבר מלך". ובזה לכאורה כוונתו לומר, שרב ראה ברבינו הקדוש גם את ענין המלכות, דלולא זאת הרי אין הוא שייך כלל להקרא משיח. ומ"מ אין זו אלא מלכות של תורה כמשה רבינו, ואין כאן את שלימות המלוכה, דעיקר המלכות היא לראש הגולה, ומשום כך אינו יכול להיות משיח בפועל.

ולכן עם כל הגדלות שיחסו רב ורבי חייא לרבינו הקדוש, עד שאמרו שמשיח הוא "כגון רבינו הקדוש", הרי כאשר הוא שאל אותם הלכה למעשה אם יש לו דין מלך, השיבו לו בשלילה. כי רק ראש הגולה שבא מזכרים דדוד ומזרע שלמה, יש בו את שלימות המלכות, כשלמה אביו שדוקא בו היתה שלימות המלכות ונתקיים בו (דברי הימים א' כט, כג) "וישב שלמה על כסא ה'" (וכמבואר באריכות בספר השיחות תנש"א ח"ב ע' ‎527-8‏ במעלת מלכות שלמה לגבי מלכות דוד). אבל גם ראש הגולה אינו יכול להיות מלך המשיח, כי אין בו את הנשיאות דתורה. ומלכות המשיח היא החיבור של שניהם, כשיכלו שני בתי אבות ויתאחדו לאחדים כאחד.

וזהו שמבואר באריכות בשיחות כ"ק אדמו"ר שליט"א, שבמלך המשיח תהיה ההתאחדות של "מלך" ו"רב". שהרי משיח "מחזיר מלכות דוד ליושנה", וגם "ילמד תורה את כל העם" (הלכות תשובה סוף פ"ט. לקו"ת צו יז,א).

יד

בדורנו – הרבי הוא המלך המשיח בפועל ממש

ובספר "שארית ישראל" להרה"צ מוילעדניק זי"ע כתב (ומובא בדא"ח), שמהבעש"ט ואילך החל להאיר ניצוץ משיח. כי מהבעש"ט החלה ההתאחדות של משיח בן דוד ומשיח בן יוסף, היינו הנשיאות בתורה והנשיאות במלכות כאחד. וזהו שנקראו הבעש"ט ותלמידיו הקדושים בשם "אדוננו מורנו ורבינו", כי על המלך אמרו בתוספתא (סנהדרין פ"א ה"ב) "וקורין אותו אדוננו ורבינו", והוסיפו "מורנו" ע"ש שמלמד תורה ועבודת ה' לכל העם וגם לאומות העולם, וכמ"ש (ישעי' ב, ג) "ויורנו מדרכיו", ופירש הרד"ק "והמורה הוא מלך המשיח".

והנה בכל השיחות שמדבר הרבי אודות כ"ק אדמו"ר מוהריי"צ נ"ע, שהוא נשיא הדור המשיח שבדור, ומקשר זה עם ענין הגאולה בפועל, הרי בודאי שכוונתו שהוא המשיח כפשוטו, גואלם של ישראל, ולא רק כמו שאמרו על רבינו הקדוש. וכלשונו הטהור בשיחת ליל שמחת תורה תשמ"ו: "נשיא דורנו הוא המשיח, עם כל הפירושים במשיח: נמשח בשמן, נבחר, מנהיג ורועה ישראל.. ולא איכפת לי אם יפרשו משיח צדקנו כפשוטו, כי כך היא המציאות האמיתית, שנשיא דורנו היה משיח בדורו והוא המשיח בדורנו".

וכשאומר הרבי שע"י ההכרזה "יחי המלך" מתגלית מציאותו של המשיח, ורק לאחר מכן באים פרטי פעולותיו שלוחם מלחמות ה' ומנצח וכו' (ספר השיחות תשנ"ב ח"א ע' ‎131-2‏), הרי אין כוונתו רק לענין תאורטי ונשמתי דמשיח בן דוד וכדומה, אלא למשיח כפשוטו שמתגלה ע"י ההכרזה "יחי המלך" ואח"כ לוחם מלחמות ה'. וכשאומר שמלך המשיח עומד על גג בית המקדש ומבשר את הגאולה, וממשיך שזהו "כפי שהכריזו ומכריזים במיוחד לאחרונה" (ספר השיחות תנש"א ע' ‎138-9‏), הרי גם בזה כוונתו למלך המשיח כפשוטו, שגואל את עם ישראל מהגלות.

ולכן, הגם שעל עצם הענין שיש משיח בכל דור, מביאים דוגמא מדברי רב על רבינו הקדוש, מ"מ יש להבחין שאין הנידון דומה לראיה ממש, אלא הוא למעלה מזה באין ערוך. שהרי בדורנו שהוא "הדור האחרון לגלות והראשון לגאולה", בודאי שנשיא הדור ש"הוגה בתורה ועוסק במצות כדוד אביו" ומלכותו והשפעתו היא בתורת הנגלה והחסידות, ובנוסף לזה מתעסק בכפית כל ישראל ובמלחמות ה', הוא המאחד את שני המשיחים, שני בתי אבות, שבט ומחוקק, והוא מלך המשיח כפשוטו, גואלן של ישראל.

ויהי רצון, שהרבי מלך המשיח שליט"א שהוא מזרע דוד ושלמה, מדכורא ומנוקבתא, אשר לוחם מלחמות ה' "ובכמה ענינים כבר מנצח", יבוא ויגאלנו ויוציא את עם ישראל ואת כל העולם בהצלחה ובשלום מהמצב הנורא שנמצאים בו, ויוליכנו קוממיות לארצנו בקרוב ממש.

http://old2.ih.chabad.info/#!g=1&url=article&id=63386

עיתון 'משפחה' קיים לפני חג הפסח שיחה מיוחדת עם הרב נפתלי הלברשטאם - האדמו"ר מצאנז גריבוב שליט"א, המתגורר בבורו פארק ועוסק רבות בשושלות יוחסין ואף הקים לשם כך מכון מיוחד.

במהלך הראיון מספר האדמו"ר על חסידויות מסוימות שביקשו את שושלת היוחסין של רבם. בין היתר נאמר בכתבה:

"חסידות נוספת שביקשה לברר את יחוס רבה היא חסידות חב"ד, ונציגיה אף הם ביקרו במקום. הבירור העלה כי האדמו"ר מליובאוויטש הוא צאצא של נחשון ועמינדב וגם צאצא של דוד המלך. ובכלל, אומר הרב הלברשטאם, כל האדמו"רים כולם הם צאצאים של דוד המלך".

יצויין עם זאת, כי כבר בספר "היום יום" מצויין הייחוס של רבותינו נשיאינו לדוד המלך.

http://www.shturem.net/index.php?section=news&id=25491#n_com_send

Comment: Interesting. I see he's descended from the daughter of the אדמו"ר הזקן so he's not a (proven) paternal descendant of David.

Comment: I just added an article on how he is also ben achar ben, but you’re right we can’t actually name them ben achar ben.

Answer (score -1):

There are many reasons to believe that the father of the Tzemach Tzedek, Reb Shalom Shachna, was a direct descendant of Dovid HaMelech.

As a proof for this i will just quote what the The Rebbe Rashab, also a direct descendant of the Tzemach Tzedek, says clearly (Toras Shalom pg. 176): At a farbrengen on Motzaei Shabbos, 21 Kislev 5673, “‘His candle will never be extinguished;’ the light of the Baal Shem Tov will constantly illuminate. Chassidus will, without a doubt, exist until the coming of Moshiach, for ‘Dovid Melech Yisroel chai v’kayam’ – this was the Baal Shem Tov and the Maggid and the Rebbe, and so on, for we are of the seed of Dovid and we will continue until Moshiach. The Rebbe will take us all out.”

Now by the way what you said in your question isnt true as there are many proofs that to be Moshiach, one does not actually have to be a direct descendant – son after son – from Dovid HaMelech, and one who is a matrilineal descendant of Dovid HaMelech can also qualify to be Moshiach. One proof is from רבינו הקדוש. We all know that the Gemara (Sanhedrin 98b) says, “Says Rav: If Moshiach is among the living, he is, for example, Rabbeinu HaKadosh.” This is despite the fact that Tosafos (Sanhedrin 5a) brings down that Rabbeinu HaKadosh says that he is a descendant of the daughter of Dovid.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: why are we to assume Rav meant to say Rabbeinu Hakadosh was Moshiach mamish? He might have meant something completely different. It _is_ a qualification of Moshiach that he be descended paternally from Dovid Hamelech, as this is how the line of Melochim is passed, and the Moshiach has to be a Melech from Beis Dovid.

Comment: Wasn't Rabbeinu HaKadosh part of the Hillel-Gamliel-Shimon line?  Are you saying the whole line is descended from David only via his daughter?  Even if they are descended from a daughter, they could also be descended from a son given that there are many generations.  Also, I didn't see this in Tos on Sanhedrin 5a.