# How was Yechoniah king after Eliakim's Davidic lineage was cursed?

Tags: messiah, genealogy, curse

[>Jer 36:30
לָכֵ֞ן כֹּֽה־אָמַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֗ה עַל־יְהֽוֹיָקִים֙ מֶ֣לֶךְ יְהוּדָ֔ה לֹא־יִֽהְיֶה־לּ֥וֹ יוֹשֵׁ֖ב עַל־כִּסֵּ֣א דָוִ֑ד וְנִבְלָתוֹ֙ תִּהְיֶ֣ה מֻשְׁלֶ֔כֶת לַחֹ֥רֶב בַּיּ֖וֹם וְלַקֶּ֥רַח בַּלָּֽיְלָה׃
Assuredly, thus said YHVH concerning King Jehoiakim of Judah: He shall not have any of his line sitting on the throne of David; and his own corpse shall be left exposed to the heat by day and the cold by night.](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.36.30?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

Eliakim is cursed, with no one "of his line sitting on the throne of David." Yet, we can see Yehoaichin sitting on the throne of David, even if only for a few months. Was the curse of Eliakim lifted? Was it a delayed fulfillment with the removal of his son?

More specifically, how can Moshiach come through the line of Eliakim if such a curse remains on his line? Is it generally believed Moshiach *must* descend through Yehoaichin as discussed in this question ([Which kings must Moshiach descend from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/which-kings-must-moshiach-descend-from))?

Comment: https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/messiahtruth/jehoiakim-curse-t394.html

Comment: the answer to the question you link to discusses the lifting of the curse

Comment: Thank you. I've been reading through the forum, though it appears to have gone off the rails a bit in the later comments.